# Making a list in R which has only 1 value in each index

Tags: r, list, vector, append

so im trying to make a list where each index ( listname[[i]]) has only 1 value.
when I assign each value manually it works but when i try assigning in a for loop it puts all of the list in index 1 (and not assigning the values i want, it assigns NULL)  clarify: I DONT want a nested list. i want a normal list with length(force1[[2]]) and in each index to assign 0 or 1 according to a condition

- force1 is a list of 2. index 1 has a string list and index 2 has a numeric list

code for testing:

```
temp_bool <- FALSE
birth_binary <- list()
birth_binary[[length(force1[[2]])]] <- 1



for (i in seq_len(length((force1[[2]])))){
  temp_bool <- as.integer(force1[[2]][i]) < as.integer(45)
  if (temp_bool == TRUE){
    append(birth_binary,list('1'))
  }
    else{
      append(birth_binary,list('0'))
    }


  }
temp_bool <- TRUE
if (temp_bool == TRUE){
  birth_binary[[5]] <- 90
```

[force 1[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYP4L.png)

[image: manual:]
[image: result of manual:]

[image: using "for" loop:]
[image: result of "for" loop]

I have tried using append() with both a value to add and a vector to add.
also tried using the assignment <-  to the i'th index.

Comment: The `range(length` seems to be an issue.  You may want `seq_len(length(`

Comment: still same issue. the problem is the fact that the loop applied on the nested list instead of main 1..

Comment: Can you add a small reproducible example instead of images for testing (with expected output) thanks

Comment: i have added a code :)

Comment: Thanks, do you have `force1` something like `force1 <- list(1:5, letters[1:6])`

Comment: force1 <- c(na.omit(starwars["gender"]),na.omit(starwars["birth_year"])) thats what is in force 1. data('starwars' , package = "dplyr") thats to load data

Comment: Based on the description and the code showed, I am guessing that you don't need a loop (as in the solution I posted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a loop, extract the second element of 'force1' list (`force1[[2]]`), check whether it is less than 45 (`< 45`), convert the logical to binary (`+` or `as.integer`) and convert the binary vector to list with `as.list` and assign to a new object 'birth_binary'

```
birth_binary <- as.list(+(force1[[2]] < 45))
```

Comment: can u explain the syntax? with the condition and all?  edit: it worked!! but please explain the syntax and maybe explain why my code didn't work?

Comment: @WalaWizon updated with some description

Comment: @WalaWizon your code is looping over the first element of birth_binary i.e. `birth_binary[[1]]` and then adding elements to it as a vector

Comment: about your explanation: where in this line of code it says to iterate over the whole list?

Comment: @WalaWizon `+(force1[[2]] < 45)` is a binary vector.  `as.list` convert to a list with each element a list element i.e. `as.list(1:5)`